# Grouping results of a groupby with too numerous cases into a "trash bin" level

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to "simplify" for reporting purposes rare events in a pandas DataFrame resulting from a group-by operation.

Let's take for example this DataFrame, where I use `colA` to count the occurrences of values in `colB`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'colA':['a','b','c','d','e','a','a','b','b','a'],'colB':[1,2,3,4,5,1,1,2,2,1]})

df_grouped = df.groupby(['colA']).agg('count')
```

The result is:

```
      colB
colA      
a        4
b        3
c        1
d        1
e        1
```

from this grouped dataframe I want to obtain a new dataframe, where the least frequent values, namely those corresponding to `colA={'c','d','e'}` are grouped in a new value of the `colA` level called `'other'`, that contains the total number of all these, like the following:

```
       colB
colA
a      4
b      3
other  3
```

Is there a simple way to perform this "put-rare-stuff-in-the-trashbin" operation?
Moreover, how can I do it in the presence of a MultiIndex?

Comment: Kindly accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark next to the solution. If there are multiple answers that have solved but you are unsure which one to accept, you can select one randomly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do it one-line

```
out = df.rename(index=dict.fromkeys(df[df.colB<2].index,'other')).sum(level=0)
Out[189]: 
       colB
colA       
a         4
b         3
other     3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
df_final = df_grouped.rename({k: 'Other' for k, v in df_grouped.colB.eq(1).items() 
                                                           if v == True}).sum(level=0)

Out[671]:
       colB
colA
a         4
b         3
Other     3
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you, I'd do something like this:

```
s = df['colA'].value_counts()
s['other'] = s[s<2].sum()
s = s[s >= 2]
print(s)
```

Output:

```
a        4
b        3
other    3
Name: colA, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following where you create a `boolean` series if equal to the minimum. Then, use `.where()` to change the `index` values:

```
s = (df_grouped['colB'] != df_grouped['colB'].min())
df_grouped.index = df_grouped.index.where(s, 'other')
df_grouped = df_grouped.sum(level='colA')
df_grouped
Out[1]: 
       colB
colA       
a         4
b         3
other     3
```